# C++ Struct: const field changes

Tags: c++, struct

I try to explain my problem as short as possible, btw I always want to find the solution by myself but i'm looking for this simple error for more than 5 hours.

Imagine i got a struct Struct:

```
struct Struct {

Struct(int i) : number(i){
    //number == 1
}

const int number;

void function() {
    //number != 1
}
};
vector<Struct*> structs;
```

Alright, no i'm gonna add one object Struct to my vector like this:

```
Struct struct(1);
structs.push_back(&struct);
//foreach cause there gonna be more structs added soon, but error occurs at the first anyway
for(Struct* ptr:structs) ptr->function();
```

Alright, that didn't work out so i debugged and found out that my **const int number**, which is set to 1 in the constructor, changes to a completely different value when i call function().

[image: Debugger in Constructor]
At this point, i'm initializing my struct with **number = 1**.
And i quess, **0x41674FEE58** is the memory address of the struct.

[image: Debugger in function]
At this point, i'm in the function. As you can see, number changed to 32762, even though it is the exact same struct(and not a copy), because this got the same memory address **0x41674FEE58**.

I know this is not a straight forward question, but maybe someone got a similar problem in the past and maybe her/his solution would work for me. Or i'm just a complete idiot, made an obvious fault and should stick with Java.

Anyways, thank you for your precious time.

//edit

this is my code i'm using, it should become an aimbot and i'm reading values from the memory.

```
while (READ_WRITE_SUCCESS) {
    Local_Player.read_Memory();
    for (CPU_Player* p : cpu_players) (*p).read_Memory();
    //cout << cpu_players.size() << endl;
    Sleep(FREQUENCY);
}
```

this is where it starts, CPU_Players are added in Local_Player.read_Memory()

```
//struct for player
struct Player {

Player() {
    coordinates.push_back(0.0f);
    coordinates.push_back(0.0f);
    coordinates.push_back(0.0f);
}

INT64 BaseAddress;
vector<float> coordinates;
char team[8] = { 0 };
float mouse_x;
float mouse_y;

int playercount;

void read_Memory() {

    //get current player baseaddress
    READ_WRITE_SUCCESS = ReadProcessMemory(process, sauerbratenexe + Offset_PlayerBase / sizeof(DWORD), &BaseAddress, sizeof(INT64), 0);
    //xyz
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_Position_x), &coordinates[0], sizeof(float), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_Position_y), &coordinates[1], sizeof(float), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_Position_z), &coordinates[2], sizeof(float), 0);
    //teamname
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_TeamName), &team, 8, 0);
    //playercount
    ReadProcessMemory(process, sauerbratenexe + Offset_PlayerCountBase / sizeof(DWORD), &playercount, sizeof(int), 0);
    --playercount;

    if (playercount != cpu_players.size() && cpu_players.size() >= 0) {
        int diff = playercount - cpu_players.size();

        //players joined
        if (diff > 0) {
            while (diff > 0) {


                //here i add my CPU_Player struct
                CPU_Player cpu(cpu_players.size()+1);
                cpu_players.push_back(&cpu);
                cout << "cpu" << cpu_players.size() << " added" << endl;
                diff--;
            }
        }//players left
        else {
            while (diff < 0) {
                cout << "cpu" << cpu_players.size() << " removed" << endl;
                cpu_players.pop_back();
                diff++;
            }
        }
    }
}
} Local_Player;
```

this is the struct for your own player. I check the playercount, and if it changed, i add/remove players with the if statement.

```
//struct for cpu
struct CPU_Player {

CPU_Player(int n) : number(n){

}

DWORD BaseAddress;
const int number;
vector<float> coordinates = { 0, 0, 0 };
char team[8] = { 0 };
int health;

void read_Memory() {

    //get current player baseaddress
    DWORD temp;
    READ_WRITE_SUCCESS = ReadProcessMemory(process, sauerbratenexe + Offset_CPUBase/sizeof(DWORD), &temp, sizeof(DWORD), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(temp + Offset_CPUBase_2*(number+1)), &BaseAddress, sizeof(DWORD), 0);
    //ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(temp + Offset_CpuPlayer*number), &BaseAddress, sizeof(DWORD), 0);
    cout.setf(ios_base::hex, ios_base::basefield);
    cout << BaseAddress << endl;
    //get health
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_Health), &health, sizeof(int), 0);
    //get xyz
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_Position_x), &coordinates[0], sizeof(float), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_Position_y), &coordinates[1], sizeof(float), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_Position_z), &coordinates[2], sizeof(float), 0);
    //team
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + Offset_TeamName), &team, 8, 0);
}
};vector<CPU_Player*> cpu_players;
```

this is the CPU_Player where const int number gets messed up.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You don't need to stick with Java but you do need to learn about the difference between stack and heap, and use of smart pointers to simplify C++ memory management. Think about where the pointer points to.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: Is this the full code? Is the code optimized? You are adding a stack-based struct, so unless you run this exactly as-is, the most likely reason is that your stack-based object went out of scope before your debugging and/or the call to function.

Comment: Your code as written looks ok to me (apart from using `struct` as variable name). But I bet in your real code variables you `push_back` go out of scope before you use them.

Comment: @Steve So if you see the error from that, you can write an answer no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        while (diff > 0) {
            //here i add my CPU_Player struct
            CPU_Player cpu(cpu_players.size()+1);
            cpu_players.push_back(&cpu);
            cout << "cpu" << cpu_players.size() << " added" << endl;
            diff--;
        }
```

The lifetime of the object called `cpu` ends at the curly brace `}` which ends the `while` loop.  You've put a pointer to it into a vector, but the object is dead, and using the pointer is invalid starting from the very next iteration of the `while` loop.

Your code doesn't demonstrate any reason to use pointers, so don't.  Declare `std::vector<CPU_Player> cpu_players;` and just do `cpu_players.push_back(cpu);`.  This will copy the object called `cpu` into another `CPU_Player` object owned by the vector.

If you later do have some reason to use pointers (maybe `CPU_Player` becomes a polymorphic base class and you want to put derived class objects in the vector), go with smart pointers instead.  This would look like

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CPU_Player>> cpu_players;
```

and

```
cpu_players.push_back(std::make_unique<CPU_Player>(cpu_players.size()+1));
```

A `unique_ptr` manages the lifetime of the pointed-at object for you, so you rarely need to worry about it.